# Normalize values from different MEMS 3-axis accelerometers

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, accuracy, resolution, sensitivity

I have to find a solution to uniform values on 3-axis accelerometers on different android devices. I mean, a device with a specific accelerometer, subjected to the same acceleration, return values, for each of 3 axis, that are different from the values returned from another android device with different accelerometer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a few measurements to get that answer. To get +1 and -1, have the user set the phone on its back and face for a few seconds. To get 0, have the user drop it a foot or two (hold it in one hand and catch it with the other) or toss it in the air briefly. As long as there isn't much rotation, the accelerometers should zero out while it's in free-fall.

In general, if A is the measurement at 1G, B is the measurement at 0G, and X is the new measurement, the scaling factor would be:

$$\left(\frac{X-B}{A-B}\right) * 1G = G_{output}$$

Edit, adding rationale for formula:

We need to take one range of values, and stretch it onto another. We can do that with a scaling function. Additionally, we are not assuming that the value of 0 is necessarily going to be measured as a numerical 0. The readable values might be between 0 and 255, covering both positive and negative sensor values, for example. We deal with that using a translation function.

It might make more sense if you imagine it on a number line.

If B is your zero value, if you subtract that from your measured value, your new value (say Y) is now centered around the 'zero' value B.

$$X-B=Y$$

Now, you need to scale that into a range that you want. We measure the range of values that represents one unit in our new scale, "1 G". This is simply the measurement at 1G (sitting on the table) and 0G (freefall). You might call the units of this new number "counts per G".

$$A-B=\frac{counts}{G}$$

If you now take your translated value Y and scale it (units included as subscripts this time)

$$\frac{Y_{counts}}{(A-B)_{\frac{counts}{G}}}=\frac{Y_{counts} \times G}{(A-B)_{counts}}=\frac{Y}{(A-B)}G=\frac{(X-B)}{(A-B)}G$$

If the units help you analyze it then great, but like I said, I was just thinking about it like moving and stretching a number line.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @Daniel. My problem is that with different devices with incorporate different accelerometers (different sensibility, different range, ecc) the reading values are really differents. I'm using now two devices and one of these has more sensitivity and bigger range than the other. For example, the two devices, subjected to the same acceleration, return me values close to -0,5g (from the device with minor sensitivity) and close to -6g (from the device with more range and sensitivity). I need that both devices return me similar values. 
How can I do that?

Comment: G_out is given as a real number. So, if you did the calibration right, the numbers are comparable in their valid ranges.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing specifically, but if you're reading values and getting .5g and 6g from the same movement with to models, something is wrong. You've configured them wrong, or some math is wrong somewhere. You would need to provide more info, and possibly this is an Android-specific programming question, which I could not answer.

Comment: I think it works now. But I have another problem. Can I reduce the maximum range with some logical formula? I would like to transform the occasional -6 values, because the other device range is +-2 and I would like to consider this last range as standard range. The easier thing would be delete these too big values but I think is a rough solution. What can I do? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Is it *actually* -6G that you're reading, or does that correspond to an actual reading of -2G? If you are truly reading -6G and want to limit the output to -2G, you should just set -2G to be the minimum value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to work. About your formula [(X-B)/(A-B)], how Did you get it?

Comment: Explanation added. Glad it worked for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot. On my version there is just a "little" difference. I adopted B as the offset for axis of interest and I don't calculate that tossing it in the air but calculating the acceleration value positioning the device at 0g for each axis.

Comment: You mean at 1g? So you set it on the front face and back face and take the difference?

Comment: Not exactly. For istance, put the device at 1g for Z axis (so screen facing upwards) and I take value for Y and X (when Z axis is at 1g other axis would be at 0g). The values of axis at 0g would be 0 but because exists offset they will be never exaclty 0. So, I make that for each position for each axis and I get the medium offset (my B) for each axis.

Comment: Ah. Just assuming that the surface is perfectly level. Got it

Comment: I have another question for you. Can I use sensitivity accelerometer calibration for my purposes too (I'm using just offset and measure at 1g with your formula now)? If Yes, How can I use sensitivity? I'm reading on some accelerometer datasheet that they are factory calibrated for sensitivity and offset and obviously these values are stored in accelerometer registers not accessible by high level programming. On your formula I use just offset, no sensitivity.

Comment: Your question was framed in a way that implies that you do not have access to those settings. You should set the sensitivity or measurement range to the range of values you want to measure. Can you mark this question as answered and ask a new one if you have more?

Comment: @Bob You're going to have to explain wanting to delete that formula if you want me to approve your edit!